# Always block with two events or multiple event

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

What is the difference between always block with one event control and with two events controls?

```
module  test;
  logic a,b;

  initial
    begin 
        a = 0;
        a = 1;
        a=0;
        a=1;
    end

  always@(posedge a)
  //    @(posedge a)
    b = a;

  initial $monitor(b); // uncommenting @(posedge a) results to 'x'. Otherwise results to '1' 
endmodule
```

Comment: `@` is an **event control statement**. Whenever `posedge` of `a` has arrived, at that time, the `@` must have been reached and **waiting on event**. If you **uncomment** this code, then it will **wait for two positive edges of `a`** before assigning value to `b`. It is a race condition since the `initial` block may execute first and then the second `@` arrives. So, `b` is never assigned any value.

Answer (score 2):

Although the "@(...)" structure is mostly seen in combination with the 'always' it is by no means the *only* place. It can also be used to wait for an event. This is normally done in test benches. 
This is some code from one of my test benches:

```
@(posedge clk) ;          
for (r=0; r<32; r=r+1)      
begin
   radrs <= r%16; 
   read  <= 1'b1;
   @(posedge clk) ;          
   radrs <= 'hx; 
   read  <= 1'b0;
   @(posedge clk) ;
   while (ready==1'b0)
      @(posedge clk);     
end
```

Coming back to your code (I removed the comment and reformatted):

```
always@(posedge a)
   @(posedge a)  b = a;
```

Thus you have an always block which is triggered by a positive edge on 'a'.
After the positive edge it waits for another positive edge on 'a' and then assigned b to a. In this case the value of 'b' will always be one after the second rising edge on 'a' and then never change.

What is more a problem is your test bench. You assign values to 'a' with no time delay. In Verilog this means there is a delta delay between them (A simulation time delay with no physical delay). If you want to see the effect of your code use this:

```
initial
begin 
    a = 0;
    #10 a = 1;
    #10 a=0;
    #10 a=1;
end
```

[image]